# Problema en la configuracion de CXF para logging SOAP y REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap

Tengo servicios SOAP y REST en mi aplicación y tengo configurado CXF con spring y xml para hacer mostrar el logging. Los servicios SOAP los muestra bien, pero los REST no. Mi configuración es la siguiente:

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

Además, utilizo slf4j y este es mi archivo logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="SOCKET" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender">
      <RemoteHost>localhost</RemoteHost>
      <Port>4560</Port>
      <ReconnectionDelay>170</ReconnectionDelay>
      <IncludeCallerData>true</IncludeCallerData>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <encoder>
           <pattern>%date{ISO8601} |-%-5level in %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.binding" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.transaction" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.orm" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.faces" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.webflow" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.ldap" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="warn" />

    <logger name="org.apache.cxf.services" level="info" />
    <logger name="org.apache.cxf.endpoint" level="info"/>

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="SOCKET"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

También he intentado crear interceptores en

```
<bean id="ContextInInterceptor" class="example.interceptors.ContextMessageInInterceptor"></bean>
<bean id="ContextOutInterceptor" class="example.interceptors.ContextMessageOutInterceptor"></bean>

<cxf:bus>
   <cxf:features>
      <cxf:logging/>
   </cxf:features>

   <cxf:inInterceptors>
      <ref bean="ContextInInterceptor"/>
   </cxf:inInterceptors>
   <cxf:outInterceptors>
      <ref bean="ContextOutInterceptor"/>
   </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

Estas son las clases que representan los beans:

```
public class ContextMessageInInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<org.apache.cxf.message.Message> {

    @Autowired
    ContextJSONInInterceptor contextJSONInInterceptor;

    public ContextMessageInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {

        if (message instanceof XMLMessage) {
            contextJSONInInterceptor.handleMessage((XMLMessage) message);
        }else{
            if(message instanceof MessageImpl){
                if(!(message instanceof SoapMessage)){
                    contextJSONInInterceptor.handleMessage(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ContextMessageOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    @Autowired
    ContextSOAPOutInterceptor contextSOAPOutInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    ContextJSONOutInterceptor contextJSONOutInterceptor;

    public ContextMessageOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.WRITE);
        addBefore(SoapOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        if (message instanceof SoapMessage) {
            contextSOAPOutInterceptor.handleMessage((SoapMessage) message);
        } else {
            if (message instanceof XMLMessage) {
                contextJSONOutInterceptor.handleMessage(message);
            }else{
                if(message instanceof MessageImpl){
                    contextJSONOutInterceptor.handleMessage(message);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

public class ContextSOAPOutInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    ContextService contextService;

    public ContextSOAPOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.WRITE);
        addBefore(SoapOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) {
    }
}

public class ContextJSONInInterceptor
        extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    ContextService contextService;

    @Autowired
    ContextJSONInInterceptor contextJSONInInterceptor;

    public ContextJSONInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        if (message instanceof XMLMessage) {
            ContextInfo contextObj = this.contextService.getContext();
            // If no locale is set in the context, take the default one
            if (contextObj.getLocale() == null) {
                contextObj.setLocale(ConfigHelper
                        .getInstance().getConfigParameter(new ConfigId(CategoryGroupEnum.ang,
                                AngConfigCategoryEnum.LANGUAGE, AngConfigParamEnum.DEFAULT_LOCALE), "en_GB")
                        .toLowerCase());
            }
        } else {
            if (message instanceof MessageImpl) {
                System.out.println("Content-Type: " + message.get(Message.CONTENT_TYPE));
                System.out.println(message.toString());
                System.out.println("---------------");
            }
        }

    }
}

public class ContextJSONOutInterceptor extends
        org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.AbstractJsonpOutInterceptor {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    ContextService contextService;

    public static final String ANG_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY = "connectionToken";

    public ContextJSONOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.WRITE);
        addBefore(SoapOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        System.out.println("Content-Type: " + Message.CONTENT_TYPE);
        System.out.println(message.toString());
        System.out.println("---------------");
    }

}
```

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal. Solo necesito que los servicios REST muestren algo parecido a mis servicios SOAP:

[image: Request]

[image: Response]

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde Stack Overflow o accediste directamente a Stack Overflow en español? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y sería útil saber el motivo, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara, explicitando que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: @lois6b Ya he editado la pregunta para que esté en español. La pregunta la he redactado en inglés porque queria dirigirme a Stack Overflow y me ha redireccionado por defecto a la versión en español.

Comment: Redireccionado?  Como intentaste llegar a SO, a traves de google?

Comment: @lois6b Si, introduje Stack Overflow y me redireccionó a la version en español